# skrollr.js data attribute into java-script file

Tags: jquery, skrollr

i use the api "skrollr.js" in my wordpress-website.

Now i have a div-box like this

```
<div data-_foobar="left:0%;" data-_foobar--100="left:50%;" data-_foobar-100="left:100%;"></div>
```

is it possible to swap this attributes into a js-file like this:

HTML:

```
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function initJarallax()
{
  //Init SkrollR
  var s = skrollr.init();

  //this function doesn´t exists
  s.addAttribute("myDiv","data-_foobar","left:0%");
  ....
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can pass it with js parameters.   Using the skrollr-stylesheets might be an option, https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anderssonola show me the best way(i think).

I do this steps:

1. download skrollr-stylesheets from [this url](http://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets)
2. add this in the header:

   link href="http://myUrl.com/wp-content/themes/FullScreenTheme/style.css"  rel="stylesheet" data-skrollr-stylesheet>
3. wrote this code

   ```
   #myDiv{
    -skrollr-animation-name:animation1;
     }

   @-skrollr-keyframes animation1 {
   data-_foobar{left:0%;}
   data-_foobar--100{left:50%;};
   ....
   }
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know skrollr, but in a jquery style you could do something like

```
$("#myDiv").attr("data-_foobar--100", "left:50%");
$("#myDiv").attr("data-_foobar-100", "left:100%");
$("#myDiv").attr("data-_foobar", "left:0%");
```

Can you jsfiddlize your case?

Comment: this work also, but in this case, you always have to refresh the page:(